# eth_sendRawTransaction:invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type hexutil.Bytes

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I call the **eth_sign** to get signature of RawTransaction, then call **eth_sendRawTransaction**,but got the error

> "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"invalid
>   argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type
>   hexutil.Bytes"}}"

I have no idea in where it is wrong.

I use some libs of web3j,this is my method:

```
public JSONObject eth_sendRawTransaction(String contract, String from, String to, double amount, long gasLimit) throws Exception {
    walletpassphrase(from) ;

    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        BigInteger nNonce = getNonce(from);

        String gasPrice = eth_gasPrice();
        BigInteger nGasPrice = Numeric.decodeQuantity(gasPrice);
        BigInteger nGasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(gasLimit);

        BigInteger nAmount = Convert.toWei(Double.toString(amount), Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigInteger();
        Function function = new Function(
                "transfer",
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(to),
                        new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(nAmount)),
                Collections.emptyList());
        String data = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);

        RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(
                nNonce,
                nGasPrice,
                nGasLimit,
                contract,
                BigInteger.ZERO,
                data);
        byte[] encodedTransaction = TransactionEncoder.encode(rawTransaction);
        String encoded = Numeric.toHexString(encodedTransaction);
        String signature = eth_sign(from, encoded);
        String signed = encoded + Numeric.cleanHexPrefix(signature);

        String s = main("eth_sendRawTransaction", "[{"+
                " \"data\": \""+signed+"\""+
                "}]");

        json = JSONObject.fromObject(s);
        System.out.println("eth_sendRawTransaction - " + json);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lockAccount(from) ;

    return json;

}
```

I think that this code is wrong in below,but i don't know how to fix.

> String signed = encoded + Numeric.cleanHexPrefix(signature);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eth_sendRawTransaction` takes a single parameter, and that parameter is expected to be a JSON string with the hex encoding of the signed transaction in it.

You're passing a JSON dictionary instead.

**EDIT**

`eth_sign` is also probably a problem. `eth_sign` prefixes the string it receives before signing it. See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign.

`eth_signTransaction` though seemingly undocumented, seems to do what you want.

Comment: main("eth_sendRawTransaction", "xxxxx") is my wrapped method,it is no problem,i'm sorry i didn't make that quite clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean that `main` is fixing things up and just sending a string?

Comment: The error message seems consistent with you passing a dictionary instead of a string.

Comment: this is finally sended to geth.>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendRawTransaction", "params":[{ "data": "0xf8670e85051f4d5c0083419ce094ec0d1e2d07d3c81bfd22eeac06115385577696f480b844a9059cbb00000000000000000000000083e0e523b6cb2f9089b706c909a65a54c988e894000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000fbde882364f9e55adcf2fe04e77ce082a5acd9c7e0a86afbab051c39caf6bdb25b09607737b8441bb0ccbd8311b6e61c384c7908ae2c875bc8d4f82cb7eb0e5a1c"}], "id": 1}

Comment: Right. You're sending a dictionary with a "data" key instead of sending a string as required by that method

Comment: [eth_sendRawTransaction](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/rpc.html#eth_sendrawtransaction) is need dictionary,i think this error is got when evm parsing the params

Comment: how to sign the raw transaction is the key

Comment: @LinChen Interesting. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction disagrees. I don't know which one to consider definitive, but the error message you shared *really* seems to indicate that a string was expected. (I'm fully willing to believe that the signed transaction is also incorrect, but one error at a time.)

Comment: send "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendRawTransaction", "params":"0xf8670e85051f4d5c0083419ce094ec0d1e2d07d3c81bfd22eeac06115385577696f480b844a9059cbb00000000000000000000000083e0e523b6cb2f9089b706c909a65a54c988e894000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000fbde882364f9e55adcf2fe04e77ce082a5acd9c7e0a86afbab051c39caf6bdb25b09607737b8441bb0ccbd8311b6e61c384c7908ae2c875bc8d4f82cb7eb0e5a1c", "id": 1}",return "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"non-array args"}}"

Comment: You sent a string for `params` instead of an array. It should be `..., "params": ["0x..."], ...`

Comment: i have resolved, use sendTransaction to transfer the token also.

Comment: the Parameter "data" contain the information of the method of transfer